# Magento 1.9.x - Create store dependent attributes for entity customer

Tags: attributes, customer, eav

Earlier add a new custom attribute `biography_desc` was added for customer:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "biography_desc", array(
    "type" => "text",
    "backend" => "",
    "label" => "Biography",
    "input" => "textarea",
    "source" => "",
    "visible" => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique" => false,
    "note" => ""

));

$attribute = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "biography_desc");


$used_in_forms = array();

$used_in_forms[] = "adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[] = "customer_account_edit";
$attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
    ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
    ->setData("is_system", 0)
    ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
    ->setData("is_visible", 1)
    ->setData("sort_order", 100);
$attribute->save();
```

Now, i had to make it store dependent, so that i could add description on differnet languages: en, fr и etc.

For products this is not a problem, because table eav_entity_text has a field store_id. And all examples where it requires to do such things work on [products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353555/how-to-save-an-attribute-value-for-a-specific-store-view).

Please advice how to solve this problem,now i can see only one solution json or create attributes `biography_desc_en`, `biography_desc_fr` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend Mage_Customer so that it does the same as Mage_Catalog and you can have store specific attributes.

Beside this you are right. Either create one attribute per store view or find a way to put it all in one.